# How can I extract an instagram username from a hyperlink to a neighboring column and keep the hyperlink on google sheets?

Tags: excel, function, hyperlink, instagram

I'm tasked with going through a long column of instagram profile URLs and creating a new adjacent column comprised of just their usernames. I could theoretically go through the list individually, copy-pasting the part between ".com/" and the last "/" and then hyperlinking each of them, but I feel like there might be a faster way.

I've experimented with formulas trying to extract only the username but to no avail. I also realized formula cells can't be hyperlinked, so I would also need a solution for that. Here what I was trying so far:

[image: formula I was trying to use]

Here the input and expected output:

| URL | User Name |
| --- | --- |
| http://instgram.com/stack_overflow/ | stack_overflow |
| http://instgram.com/stackoverflowing/ | stackoverflowing |
| http://instgram.com/stackoverflowthestack/ | stackoverflowthestack |
| http://instgram.com/stackoverflowingstacks/ | stackoverflowingstacks |

The end result should look like **User Name** Column and be adjustable for any length of usernames (slashes and spaces among other special characters cannot be used in instagram usernames).

Also, I'm unsure why my google docs takes semi-columns instead of commas as I'm used to with Excel, but it is what it is.

Figuring this out would save me loads of time in the long-run and I would be very appreciative.

Comment: could you provide us with some samples of data or print screen

Comment: Yes, sorry! I thought it was already attached, but here's a link. I removed the formulas I tried though because it was irrelevant

Comment: please try the below formula

=LEFT(RIGHT(A1,FIND("com/",A1,2)-2),FIND("/",RIGHT(A1,FIND("com/",A1,2)-2),1)-1)

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. Upon copy pasting your formula I get a "formula parse error".

Comment: could you share your print screen for the error

Comment: it's working with me, check the below link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MZGY8Y4YuVly6vGkyX9TUfDRrx7dgj0P8UbBEHbT4aU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Yep, I see that on your doc. I made a new doc and now I am getting values, but not the right ones.. I added the picture to the original post

Comment: Could you share your sheet link here

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `TEXTAFTER` (Office Insider Beta only, Windows: 2203 (Build 15104), Mac: 16.60 (220304)). You don't have to deal with `LEFT/RIGHT/FIND` functions.  On `B2` cell you enter and expand down the following formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTAFTER(A1,"/",-2),"/","")
```

Here is the output:
[image: sample excel file]

You can replace `SUBSTITUTE` as follow via `TEXTBEFORE` to remove the last `/`:

```
=TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A1,"/",-2),"/")
```

### Explanation

The main idea is that:

```
TEXTAFTER(text,delimiter,[instance_num], [match_mode], 
 [match_end], [if_not_found])
```

allows to search backward, using the third input argument: `instance_num` (with a negative number). We are interested in the penultimate occurrence of `/`, therefore this input argument would be `-2`.

### Alternative Solution

If such functions are not available for your excel version the following works using `MID(text, start_num, num_chars)` function:

```
=LET(url, A1, length, LEN(url), count, length-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(url,"/",""))-1,
 startPos, FIND(" ",SUBSTITUTE(url,"/"," ",count))+1, numChars, length-startPos,
 MID(url,startPos, numChars))
```

**Note**: We use `LET` to avoid repeating the same calculation and also to make it easier to understand. Without `LET` it's a bigger formula but it works too:

```
=MID(A1, FIND(" ",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/"," ",
 LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))-1))+1, LEN(A1) - 
(FIND(" ",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/"," ",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))-1))+1))
```

we are looking for the penultimate `/` so `count` name achieves that:

```
count, length-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(url,"/",""))-1
```

The following formula:

```
startPos, FIND(" ",SUBSTITUTE(url,"/"," ",count))+1
```

is a way to replace just the penultimate `/` by space ( ). URLs don't have spaces so it is a good replacement. Then finding the position of such space plus `1` will give us the starting position required by `MID`. Having the starting position and the `length` of the URL we can calculate the number of characters (`numChars`), so we can finally invoke `MID` with the required input arguments.

**Note**: The approach you tried in your question, relies on specific pattern of the URL (ending with `.com`) the above approaches don't have such constraint, so you can use the following URL: `https://www.redcross.org/` and it works.